# Website does not have post previews when viewing on mobile

Tags: wordpress, blog, mobile, responsive-webdesign

For some reason when I view [my site](http://headachefreelife.com) on mobile devices the homepage just displays the full article one after the other as opposed to thumbnail and text previews. Any idea what the reason behind this is? Or how I can possibly change how my site looks on mobile devices.

Comment: Can you please share a link? Some themes do not show this information in order to adapt to smaller screens.

Comment: Hi, the link is in my profile. Upon further investigation it shows post previews on some devices but not all. Problem is, the content on the home page resizes to fit devices, but when you click on an actual post you have to scroll horizontally to see the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

It shows OK on my iPhone. I checked the demo page of this theme (justblue) on my phone and the only major difference I noticed is the non-responsive adsense block on mobile causing some trouble with responsiveness. You can try disabling that block for mobile devices or using a responsive block instead.

Comment: Are you referring to the adsense link units?... Have you tried to look at an actual post on the site on your iphone? For me on an android device i have to scroll horizontally to see the website. Also, how can I go about disabling ads for mobile devices?

Comment: Yes, adsense link units. Yes, I checked the post. You can hide ad units using the modernizr script that is being loaded on your website or try adding css property `display:none;` after targeting the ad unit in the media query block for smaller screens. So something like: `@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
#adunit {display:none;}
}`